# Is this the correct way to add filtering?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My index/landing/home page displays all images from my images table with the newest submissions on top. I'm thinking about adding filtering by:

1. Adding `<a>` elements with URLs like `www.domain.com/hot` and `www.domain.com/trending`.
2. Making my home route `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');` have an optional parameter like `Route::get('/{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');`
3. Based on the optional parameter, I'll send different $images variable to the view:

   ```
   public function index($filter){
       if ($filter == 'hot') {
           $images = hot images;
       } else if ($filter == 'trending') {
           $images = get trending images;
       } else {
           $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
       }
       return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
   }
   ```

   I haven't used real code for getting hot and trending images as I haven't figured out how to determine whether an images is hot or trending yet but you get the point.

Is this the correct way of creating filtering? Are there any better ways of doing it?

Comment: switch statement would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a switch statement to keep things nice and tidy.

```
   switch($filter) { 
     case 'hot'     : $images = hot images;break;
     case 'trending': $images = get trending images;break;
     default        : $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
   }
```

If you wish to keep it a bit more manageable you might opt for an array that the supporting code searches for the correct method to call using the `$object->{variable with string}()` method to dynamically access that function.

When you add new items to the array, you only have to make the providing method and the array entry `'newest' => 'getNewestImages',` for example.

```
private $image_getters = [
       'hot' => 'getHotImages',
       'trending' => 'getTrendingImages',
   ];

   public function index($filter)
   {
        $images = $this->getImages();
        return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
   }

   protected function getImages($filter) 
   {
        if(array_key_exists($filter, $this->image_getters)) {
            $getter = $this->image_getters[$filter];
            $images = $this->{$getter}();
       }
       else {
            $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
       }
       return $images;
   }
```

Comment: But other than that, this is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @Bobimaru I added an example of how I would do it to keep things manageable with only one array to update if there's a new getter.